# (3D touch) How to open a specific page in the application when the user kill the application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using [3D Touch and Quick Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/3d-touch#quick-actions) to navigate to "Search" page in my application.

I handle event click Shortcut button at method **PerformActionForShortcutItem()** of **AppDelegate.cs:**:

```
    public override void PerformActionForShortcutItem(UIApplication application, UIApplicationShortcutItem shortcutItem, UIOperationHandler completionHandler)
    {
        bool handledShortCutItem = HandleShortCutItem(shortcutItem);
        completionHandler(handledShortCutItem);
    }
```

- At method **HandleShortCutItem()**, I send a **MessagingCenter** to **MainPageViewModel.cs**:

```
 MessagingCenter.Send(new SearchContactEventMessage(), nameof(SearchContactEventMessage));
```

- At method **Initialize()** of **MainPageViewModel.cs**, I subscribe the above **MessagingCenter**:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SearchContactEventMessage>(this, nameof(SearchContactEventMessage), message =>

    {

        // TODO Open page Search in my app 
        .....
    }
```

It's work (can open "search" page) when my app is running foreground or background.

If my app don't open or user kill it, "Search" page couldn't be showed.

Can give me an idea when user "kill" app and they use "Quick Actions", my application can show a certain page in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

Once you click and send the `MessagingCenter` when user "kill" app, in you `MainPageViewModel.cs`, it has not subscribe the `MessagingCenter` because your app is terminated. So, it **won't** receive the `MessagingCenter` and Open page Search in your app.

**Solution:**

I would suggest you open search page directly in the `handledShortCutItem` method.

Comment: but method ```handledShortCutItem() ``` of ```AppDelegate.cs``` (iOS). Is there another idea? I want open a page with a view of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @BillNguyen When did you subscribe the MessagingCenter in MainPageViewModel.cs? If you subscribe  it once you app is open, can you add a little delay before send the MessagingCenter  in HandleShortCutItem()?

Comment: Oh, Good iDea, Thanks! It's work


```
while (Mobile.App.IsInMainPage == false)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false); 
                        }
```